# dailyLimitExceededUnreg: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

Note: Before Posting i read similar questions in stack overflow.

Hi, I am using **google-api-client** **-v '0.9.8'** newer i am getting issue

```
client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load("/home/secrets.json")
@auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization
        @auth_client.update!(
          :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
          :access_type => "offline", #will make refresh_token available
          :approval_prompt =>'force',
          :redirect_uri => 'http://someurl.com'
        )
 url = @auth_client.authorization_uri 
link = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?#{url.query}"
```

when you click on link a url will it will be redirected to a page where **code** will be genrated

```
@auth_client.code = "generated code"
@auth_client.fetch_access_token!
```

To Generate ***access_token*** and ***refresh_token***

```
service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
response = service.list_events('primary',max_results: 10,single_events: true,order_by: 'startTime',time_min: Time.now.iso8601)
```

This point issue will arise

```
dailyLimitExceededUnreg: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.
```

FYI
I enabled google calendar api in google developer console.

If anyone resolved this issue please let me know.

Comment: Isn't it just the problem that you have exceeded the daily limit for API requests? Isn't it enough to log in to the Google API dashboard and set the limit to a higher value?

Comment: I have seen that as well quota has not changed at all my daily quota is full.

Comment: Not even used a single request.

Comment: To me it looks like you're not actually using your authenticated login, rather it is falling back to unauthenticated. Your code displays ``service`` having a new calendar service instantiated, however where are the auth credentials being passed to that?

Comment: Hi @NabeelAmjad auth_client.code = "generated code", 
auth_client.fetch_access_token! .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your `@auth_client.fetch_access_token!` in a variable (such as `access_code = @auth_client.fetch_access_token!`)

Try

```
service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
service.key = access_code # if this does not work try service.authorization = access_code
response = service.list_events('primary',max_results: 10,single_events: true,order_by: 'startTime',time_min: Time.now.iso8601)
```

If that fails I'd suggest to have a look at the official [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ruby#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name) for calendar service (Ruby)

Comment: service.authorization = access_token, worked thanks Nabeel

Comment: No problem @priya :)